# B2B Commerce Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, b2b-commerce, b2b

Currently working on B2B Commerce Lightning Store and we have enabled guest view but now the client requires guest cart session. Currently in the B2B Commerce Lightning when we click on the "add to cart" button it redirects to the login page, instead, he wants to have a cart session being maintained before login, and when a customer wants to check out the promot to the login window. I am new in B2B Commerce and not sure how we can customize code. I can't find any source code and don't know where to start.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: this is limitation right now with b2b commerce lightning. You can't create the cart session before login

Answer (score 0):

I have seen someone build an interesting work around where they had each guest user go through a "ghost registration" when they tried to add products to the cart so they would be able. They were defaulted to a buyer group and standard pricebook. Then there was an option to go through a more thorough registration to update information.
But yes, I have gotten this request a few times and it is not something Salesforce has anything in place for and definitely cannot be done declaratively.